# Get numbers from list and draw pattern

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I have the following list `[2,7,4]`. I need to take numbers from the list, and I want to get output like this:

```
    *
    *
    *
    *  *
    *  *
 *  *  *
 *  *  *
[2, 7, 4]
```

I wrote the following:

```
a=eval(input())

for j in range(len(a)):
    
    print(a[j],end=" ")
    for i in range(0,a[j]):
        
        print(" *",end=" ")
            
    print()
```

But when I give this list I get this output:

> 2  *  *
> 7  *  *  *  *  *  *  *
> 4  *  *  *  *

Comment: I have added an answer to your question, I hope it is clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Printing is always done from top to bottom, so you need to find the largest number in the array to be able to print it topdown.

Then you have to loop from that number back to zero and print an asterisk where appropriate. You can see the number in this case as the height. For example, if the height is 6, an asterisk must be printed only in the second column (because 7 >= 6) and if the height is 3, an asterisk need to be printed in the last two columns (because 7 >= 3 and 4 >= 3). This is what it looks like in code:

```py
arr = [2, 7, 4]
max_num = max(arr)

# Determine if an asterisk or a space needs to be printed, based on a array
# element and the current height. 
def calc_output(array_element, cur_height):
    if array_element >= cur_height:
        return "*"

    return " "

# Loop from max_num to 1.
for x in range(max_num, 0, -1):
    line = ""

    # For every element in arr, determine if an asterisk need to be printed.
    for elem in arr:
        line += "{} ".format(calc_output(elem, x))
    
    print(line)

# Print the elements of arr separated with a space.
print(*arr)
```

This outputs:

```
  *   
  *   
  *   
  * * 
  * * 
* * * 
* * * 
2 7 4
```

It also works for any other numeric list. For example, with `arr = [4, 1, 3, 0, 4]`:

```
*       * 
*   *   * 
*   *   * 
* * *   * 
4 1 3 0 4
```

Comment: It writes None instead of space.

Comment: Maybe because I wrote it in python 3. What if you change this line `line += "{} ".format(calc_output(elem, x))` to this `line += "%s " % calc_output(elem, x)`?

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this problem if you consider the following:

1. You need to know the maximum value in the list, so you know how many rows you will need to print. Considering `[2, 7, 4]` is your list, `7` is the maximum value.
2. You can easily print the following pattern using a for loop and the value of the maximum value (`max_value`):

```
for i in range(max_value):
    print(i)
```

Which output is:

```
7
6
5
4
3
2
1
```

3. For each element in the list, at each row, `'* '` is printed if the element in the list is less than or equal to the current index `i` in the for loop. Otherwise, `'  '` is printed.
4. Once a row has been printed, you need to move to the next line.
5. Finally, you just print the list.

The following code is an implementation of the algorithm discussed above. I have added in-line comments showing the step of the algorithm:

```py
l = l = [2, 7, 4]

max_value = max(l)

for i in range(max_value, 0, -1):
  for e in l:
    print('* ' if e >= i else '  ', end='')
  print()
print(*l)

max_value = max(l) # 1

for i in range(max_value, 0, -1): # 2
  for e in l:
    print('* ' if e >= i else '  ', end='') # 3
  print() # 4
print(*l) # 5
```

**Output**

```
  *   
  *   
  *   
  * * 
  * * 
* * * 
* * * 
2 7 4
```

Keep in mind that this will work for elements in the list between `0` and `9` (inclusive).